# Track Service Bus Message Topic Subscription

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I have a service bus topic subscription model . I am in control of designing the sender component to a topic. however receiver is a remote server whose code i cannot control. Now the tricky part, is i need to somehow possibly know some stats from service bus without really having to ask the remote server to do additional work.

For eg.
1)Last message processed (it's content)
2)Last message completed succesfully - Time and content.

This is for basic troubleshooting on my word to know, that message has atleast been recieved by the receiver.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: On the topic level, you can see the number of message that are active.

Answer (score 4):

What does it mean "Last message processed" and "Last message completed succesfully". If you have a constant stream of messages, at what point you would determine what's a last message.

What you're asking is somewhat in violation of the pub/sub concept. The whole point of topics and subscriptions is to decouple publishers and subscribers.

> This is for basic troubleshooting on my word to know, that message has atleast been recieved by the receiver.

When messages are sent to the subscription queue, they are either consumed or eventually end up in the dead-letter queue. If they are in the dead-letter queue, you'll know the reason. In case they are consumed, you will have to trust the consumer it knows what it's doing. Any time of "reply" or "acknowledgement" goes against the concept of events, where you broadcast of something that has happened and should not carry if it was received or not.